# Using a {{expression}} inside ng-repeat to keep a count on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This throws a Syntax error. because of `{{count}}` inside of a ng-repeat.

**I have a button that adds +1 to count:**

```
<a href="#"  ng-click="addCount()">Add count</a>
```

**Controller function:**

```
     $scope.count = 0;     
     $scope.addCount = function() {
          $scope.count++;
          alert($scope.count);
      };
```

I would like this count to control the array index of a model::

```
$scope.img = [[

      {
        'src': 'runner-922.png',
        'klass': 'h9'
      },
      {
        'src': 'tweet.jpg',
        'klass': 'h3'
      }
   ],
      {
        'src': 'runner-922x.png',
        'klass': 'h9'
      },
      {
        'src': 'tweetx.jpg',
        'klass': 'h3'
      }
   ]
```

Which will be looped through using `ng-repeat`:

```
  <div ng-repeat="i in img[{{count}}]" class="item {{i.klass}}" >
       <img ng-src="images/iphone/{{i.src}}" alt="">             
  </div>
```

Comment: You could use a nested ng-repeat. What you're doing just seems fraught with peril.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this

```
  <div ng-repeat="i in img[{{count}}]" class="item {{i.klass}}" >
       <img ng-src="images/iphone/{{i.src}}" alt="">             
  </div>
```

to this

```
  <div ng-repeat="i in img[count]" class="item {{i.klass}}" >
       <img ng-src="images/iphone/{{i.src}}" alt="">             
  </div>
```

[See this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BeAWL8E3sNfQTmDJWfBD?p=preview)

Comment: If this has resolved your problem, you can choose this as the accepted answer.